# Ionic 4 - Platform.resume event calling

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 app in which we have three tabs. Each tab contains data which will be retrieved from api call. The data will change frequently.

When we move between tabs the api will be called and the data will be re-binded. We had a requirement that when the app is minimized and open again the api has to be called and the data has to be re-binded.

I used the platform resume event as below in all the three tabs.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.platform.resume.subscribe((e) => {
           // API call of each function (different api for tabs)
      });
});
```

Now, When the app is resumed after minimized, the platform resume event is called by it is calling multiple times as I used resume event in all the three tabs.

Please help to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: perform resume event in app.component.ts to avoid multiple calling

Comment: I will be calling different api for different tab. How should I use it in app.component.ts file? Do you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but what I gather from your question and comments, it would make sense to have a subject that will update on resume and on each tab have the function that request each API listening to that observable?

something like this: (on main app)

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.platform.resume.subscribe((e) => {
           this.appResumedSubject.next(true);
      });
});
```

and on tab1:

```
 this.appResumedObservable.subscribe(result => {
      if(result){
         this.apiCall1();
      }
 });
```

and on tab2:

```
 this.appResumedObservable.subscribe(result => {
      if(result){
         this.apiCall2();
      }
 });
```

to make it work seamlessly on both tabs it would be needed to have appResumeSubject defined on a service provider.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will work on the idea provided and let you know.